# Is this the code for a Java insertion sort? Why use the extra variable?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I just wrote the following code and I'm not sure if it's the correct implementation of insertion sort in Java (it looked too similar to bubble sort for me to be sure).

```
public static void insertionsort (int[] arr){
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j>=0; j--){
            
             if (arr[j]<arr[j-1]){
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = temp;
            }
                            
         }
        
    }
    
}
```

When I've compared mine to solutions online I noticed that they all use a variable to store arr[i].
for example:

```
void sort(int arr[]) 
{ 
    int n = arr.length; 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) { 
        int key = arr[i]; 
        int j = i - 1; 

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are 
           greater than key, to one position ahead 
           of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) { 
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; 
            j = j - 1; 
        } 
        arr[j + 1] = key; 
    } 
}
```

What is the purpose of this key variable? Isn't a little redundant?

Comment: Have you tried running your code?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the key variable is to hold the value which will be inserted into its sorted position after the inner loop. As it seems now your solution does not sufficiently work for insertion sort.